# Hinge to lift up & out for an inset lid

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, hinges

I'm creating a new lid for my TV lift. I had one made a while ago, but the guy used a cheap piano hinge that was *ever so slightly* off, so one corner of the lid poked up out of the surface and it drove me crackers. So this time I'm doing it myself, and I want a completely seamless lid (i.e. no hinges poking up); but I am a very, very amateur carpenter.

I originally bought some invisible Soss-style hinges, but a) there's very little clearance either side, b) I'm terrified of screwing up the alignment, and c) I'm using obeche wood, and that stuff is not very forgiving.

Then I had the idea of using cabinet-style mounted hinges, which would be completely hidden and I wouldn't have to go into the edge of the wood at all. Unfortunately the ones I bought are VERY stiff, and then seem to **snap!** and *lock* into a 90° position:

[image: Surface-mounted cabinet hinge in the close position]
[image: Surface-mounted cabinet hinge locked in an open position]

As it's for a TV lift, I can't have the lid 'lock' in an open position, otherwise it will never close when the TV goes back down.

So I'm looking for a hinge that will open UP and OUT:
[image: Illustration of the side profile of my TV lift lid, with a hypothetical hinge design]

I've found hinges like this one: https://www.leevalley.com/en-gb/shop/hardware/hinges/40647-concealed-lid-hinges?item=00H5401 (although I'm in the UK, so this link is no help), but they mostly seem to be for top-mounted lids, whereas mine is INSIDE.

Is there anything available that will do what I'm after?

Comment: The stiffness you mentioned is because there's massively more leverage on them after a lid panel is attached. Perception of that force is reduced fivefold or more. It's not an undesirable trait. Unless you're going for extremely tight gaps, that's what you need.

Comment: how much of a gap is there between the stationary and movable parts? ... the 2nd diagram shows a lid that would never open because of interference between parts ... there may be a hinge available that allows the lid to lift vertically  and then swing

Comment: @isherwood I actually just did a test (using the old lid), and those incredibly stiff hinges do EXACTLY what I want: lifting it up and then out... but the little pneumatic-style mechanism inside it that makes it incredibly stiff create way, _way_ too much resistance in the first instance (it actually snapped off the piece of wood I'd wood-glued into place!); and then, as suspected, after a point they SNAP to being vertical. So ideally I need the _exact same hinge_, but without the thing that provides the resistance ‍♀️

Comment: So take your Dremel and a cutoff wheel and snip the spring.

Comment: @isherwood I don't have a Dremel unfortunately. Plus the mechanism looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/BDFAvEO.jpg - I definitely don't want to cut through either of the bars holding it in place, otherwise those hinge points would be lost, and the thing itself is far too large to go through, I suspect. However it's only held in place by its own (incredibly high!) tension; so if I can figure out a way to 'push' it out, but getting any kind of purchase and applying enough pressure are incredibly difficult.

Comment: Ha! Good one. Like any self-respecting DIYer doesn't have (or have access to) a Dremel. You crack me up. There's probably a coil spring inside those sleeves. A couple slices lengthwise would probably do.

Comment: That "spring mechanism" looks like it's only held in position by the hollowed out profile on each end. You should be able to slip a flat screwdriver in there and pop them out.

Comment: @brhans That's exactly what I did! It took a _lot_ of effort - those springs are absolute monsters. https://imgur.com/a/3bonFZ6

Comment: In the future, you may consider posting questions like this at the [woodworking.se] sister site. There is a lot of woodworking knowledge there, and cabinet building (of which door/hinge installation is an important detail) is well covered. Also, there are several frequent posters from the UK who would be able to direct you to material readily available to you..

Comment: @FreeMan Ah, I didn't even realise there was a woodworking SE! That makes more sense. The last time I posted a question like this, there wasn't one, but I'll definitely be doing that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a test and mounting the hinges I already had, it absolutely worked the way I wanted, lifting the lid up and out. The main problem being that they were incredibly stiff and 'locked' into a 90° position once opened.

I used a flathead screwdriver and, with a decent amount of effort, was able to pry the encased spring mechanism out:

[image: Surface-mounted hinge with the 'soft close' spring removed]

For anyone interested, the hinge in question is [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07WHNZ1V7/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) - a Wandefol surface-mounted kitchen cabinet door hinge.

Comment: Do the hinges still function properly now that the spring is gone? What holds the hinge open so the door panel doesn't crash down onto your TV, knocking it off its pedestal and onto the floor? I'm glad this is working for you, but it's not yet a particularly useful answer for others who may come behind you looking to do something similar.

Comment: @FreeMan That's not really how TV lifts like this work - what I've done is effectively no different from fitting a regular 'free-swinging' hinge, or similar to the piano hinge that was fitted on my old TV lift lid. The lid is lifted up by a kind of hook on the top of the TV lift, and because the lid faces down, it basically just uses gravity to rest against the TV lift as it goes back down. This is very common: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xs5hr5oT1LU

Comment: That does make sense and is what I was thinking. Thanks for providing clarity - I'm sure it will be helpful for others, as well.